# FBX model from makehuman has broken rig on import

Tags: rigging, import, makehuman

I've exported the default makehuman body as an .fbx set to metres as the units, and imported it into Blender with *Import Normals*, *Import Animation*, *Import User Properties*, *Import Enums as Strings*, *Ignore Leaf Bones* and *Automatic Bone Orientation* all selected. However, the model and rig import like this:

[image: Weird rig]

I'm using Blender 2.76

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The current semi-official MakeHuman advice is to not use FBX in the first place, when the end goal is Blender.

MakeHuman has two alternative pipelines that directly target Blender, each of which is more likely to work than when going via FBX.

- The traditional one is MHX2. This is a tried and stable approach, which has been in use for many years, and which should work with most blender versions, including 2.80. See https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/overview
- The new approach is available starting with MakeHuman 1.2.0 alpha 1, and allows fetching a rigged mesh directly from a running makehuman instance without having to go via a file export. This works in blender 2.79 and 2.80. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAwfR-G813g

If you want to stick with FBX anyway, you could try the latest alpha of makehuman, see http://www.makehumancommunity.org/content/downloads.html. There are known issues with rigging in this version too though, but it's possible it might work better as parts of the routine has been rewritten.